# How to disable dojo 1.6.1 plugin on my Domino 8.5.3 server

Tags: xpages

Currently I am try to solve a bug in an application. Therefor I need the 1.4.3 dojo version. 
On my 8.5.3 Domino server, by default there will be the 1.6.1 dojo version loaded. 
This version is somewhere in a plugin, and not in the data\domino\js directery. The highest version is 1.5.1.

If I use the property 'xsp.client.script.dojo.version' in the xsp.properties file to set the required dojo version. It is not picked up by the database.

So where can I disable the 1.6.1 dojo version?

Answer (score 5):

There is a known bug in 8.5.3 where the xsp.client.script.dojo.version is not honored if the setting to aggregate the CSS and JS is enabled on the Xpages panel of the application properties.

Disabling the "Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources" setting will allow your Xpage application to run with the lower version of dojo specified.

Answer (score 2):

In 8.5.2 you had to set xsp.client.script.dojo.version in the server's xsp.properties. With 8.5.3 if you set it in the Application's xsp.properties, the setting is honoured. There's currently no option to set it at XPage level.

IBM are aware of the issue with "Use optimized runtime JavaScript and CSS resources" setting, so hopefully it will be fixed in 8.5.3 FP1.

Check out my blog post on this, shortly after 8.5.3 went gold http://www.intec.co.uk/domino-8-5-3-greater-power-over-dojo-thanks-ibm-for-your-work/